# Any idea why internet explorer doesn't save the session cookie?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, session, session-cookies

I use rails 3.0.11. In Internet Explorer the session cookie is not saved (at least I don't see it) but in other browsers (chrome, Firefox) it shows.

Comment: Do you use subdomains? Name them here if you do.

Comment: yes. www is a subdomain also.

Comment: what do you mean name them here? I have two subdomains: www.mydomain.com and htzone.mydomain.com

Comment: Your `initializers/session_store.rb` contains option `:domain => ".mydomain.com"`? (be sure to restart you app after modification this file)

Comment: I tried it just now. Still don't see rails session cookie

Comment: Just a thought, have you made sure that IE accepts cookies? I'm not familiar with the default security level of it, but that is one obvious issue?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Internet Eplorer does save the session cookie, but it doesn't show it on the developer tools. I used Fiddler to see session cookies information in ie.